# Pyqt5 threading and progress bar

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, progress-bar

"I have made a small app that get data from sqlite3.
I have added a function that moves some data from 1 table to 3 others. All work fine.... But I would like to connect the function with some progress bar to see the status.

so far i have this code

main.py

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlFunctions as Database
import threading


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 420, 391, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 280, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MoveClientsToThred)

    def MoveClientsToThred(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.MoveClientsTo, daemon=True).start()

    def MoveClientsTo(self):
        Database.MoveClientsToTables("2020")


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Move Data"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and my sql functions placed on this file

sqlFunctions.py

```py
import  sqlite3

# connect to Db file
connection = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db", check_same_thread=False)
connection.text_factory = lambda b: b.decode(errors='ignore')

def MoveClientsToTables(year):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT costum_id FROM pelates""")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for i in result:
        costum_id = (i[0])
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Mytable( costum_id, year ) VALUES(?,?) ', (costum_id, year))
        connection.commit()
```

I would like when pushbutton clicked to get percent of proccess

Thank you

Comment: Sorry but your question is too broad (see the [tour] and [ask]), and its code is completely insufficient (and with invalid syntax). In any case, you cannot directly access UI elements from external threads, so I strongly suggest you to do some research on QThread implementation on PyQt.

Comment: Hey,sorry for invalid syntax I was typing from my phone and I try to make it clear but I failed I guess. I want from sqlite3 process to get percent of what have been done so I can pass the number to progress bar

Comment: Then wait until you get to a computer, then take your time, read the above links, and try to improve your question. Also consider that StackOverflow is not a tutorial website, nor a code provider. If you attempted to achieve this, provide a [mre]. Also, review the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @musicamante is more clear and ok the question?

Comment: Please do some research on how to properly use QThread and signals. Consider that there's no guarantee that you'll be able to achieve what you need in a proper way, as it completely depends on how the sql interface responds. That said, as explained before, your question is still too broad, and we cannot really answer it properly: as explained in the tour (which it seems you didn't take yet), we can only answer to *specific, detailed questions*.